# CUDA performance doubts

Tags: performance, cuda, bandwidth, gpu

Since i didnt got a response from the CUDA forum, ill try it here:

After doing a few programs in CUDA ive now started to obtain their effective bandwidth. However i have some strange results, for example in the following code, where i can sum all the elements in a vector(regardless of dimension), the bandwidth with the Unroll Code and the "normal" code seems to have the same median result(around 3000 Gb/s)
I dont know if im doing something wrong(AFAIK the program works fine) but from what ive read so far, the Unroll code should have a higher bandwidth.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define elements 1000
#define blocksize 16    


__global__ void vecsumkernel(float*input, float*output,int nelements){



    __shared__ float psum[blocksize];
    int tid=threadIdx.x;

    if(tid + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x < nelements)
    psum[tid]=input[tid+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x];
    else
    psum[tid]=0.0f;
    __syncthreads();

    //WITHOUT UNROLL

    int stride;     
    for(stride=blockDim.x/2;stride>0;stride>>=1){
            if(tid<stride)
                    psum[tid]+=psum[tid+stride];
    __syncthreads();
    }
    if(tid==0)
            output[blockIdx.x]=psum[0];


    //WITH UNROLL
 /*
    if(blocksize>=512 && tid<256) psum[tid]+=psum[tid+256];__syncthreads();
    if(blocksize>=256 && tid<128) psum[tid]+=psum[tid+128];__syncthreads();
    if(blocksize>=128 && tid<64) psum[tid]+=psum[tid+64];__syncthreads();


    if (tid < 32) {
            if (blocksize >= 64) psum[tid] += psum[tid + 32];
            if (blocksize >= 32) psum[tid] += psum[tid + 16];
            if (blocksize >= 16) psum[tid] += psum[tid + 8];
            if (blocksize >=  8) psum[tid] += psum[tid + 4];
            if (blocksize >=  4) psum[tid] += psum[tid + 2];
            if (blocksize >=  2) psum[tid] += psum[tid + 1];
    }*/

    if(tid==0)
            output[blockIdx.x]=psum[0];



}

void vecsumv2(float*input, float*output, int nelements){
    dim3 dimBlock(blocksize,1,1);
    int i;

    for(i=((int)ceil((double)(nelements)/(double)blocksize))*blocksize;i>1;i(int)ceil((double)i/(double)blocksize)){
            dim3 dimGrid((int)ceil((double)i/(double)blocksize),1,1);
            printf("\ni=%d\ndimgrid=%u\n ",i,dimGrid.x);

            vecsumkernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(i==((int)ceil((double)(nelements)/(double)blocksize))*blocksize ?input:output,output,i==((int)ceil((double)(nelements)/(double)blocksize))*blocksize ? elements:i);
    }

 }

 void printVec(float*vec,int dim){
    printf("\n{");
    for(int i=0;i<dim;i++)
            printf("%f ",vec[i]);
    printf("}\n");
 }

 int main(){
    cudaEvent_t evstart, evstop;
    cudaEventCreate(&evstart);
    cudaEventCreate(&evstop);


    float*input=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*(elements));
    for(int i=0;i<elements;i++)
            input[i]=(float) i;


    float*output=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*elements);



    float *input_d,*output_d;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&input_d,elements*sizeof(float));

    cudaMalloc((void**)&output_d,elements*sizeof(float));



    cudaMemcpy(input_d,input,elements*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    cudaEventRecord(evstart,0);

    vecsumv2(input_d,output_d,elements);

    cudaEventRecord(evstop,0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(evstop);
    float time;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time,evstart,evstop);
    printf("\ntempo gasto:%f\n",time);
    float Bandwidth=((1000*4*2)/10^9)/time;
    printf("\n Bandwidth:%f Gb/s\n",Bandwidth);


    cudaMemcpy(output,output_d,elements*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


    cudaFree(input_d);
    cudaFree(output_d);
    printf("soma do vector");
    printVec(output,4);



   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your unrolled code has a lot of branching in it. I count ten additional branches. Typically branching within a warp on a GPU is expensive because all threads in the warp end up waiting on the branch (divergence).

See here for more info on warp divergence:

http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=74842

Have you tried using a profiler to see what's going on?

Comment: I took the unroll code from a Nvidia reduction.pdf. I dont know what is the purpose of a profiler(i have only started working with cuda a month ago, and computer engineering/programming is not my area)

Comment: Also, how do you count 10 additional branches?

Comment: I'm counting the "if"s. You're not doing ten the each time but there's lots of possible code paths and each branch may cause warp divergence.

Answer (score 3):

3000 Gb/s Does not make sense. The max bus speed of PCIe is 8Gb/s on each direction.

Take a look at this paper [Parallel Prefix Sum](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html) to gain insight on how to speed up your implementation.
Also consider that the [thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/) library have this already implemented in the [Reductions](http://thrust.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.0/doc/html/group__reductions.html) module

Comment: I though the value was really high, but i found the bandwidth with a formula i saw on the CUDA Programming Guide:

float Bandwidth=((1000*4*2)/10^9)/time; // BW=(Bytesread+Byteswrite)/10^9/time

Answer (score 1):

your not-unrolled code is invalid. For `stride<32` some threads of the same warp enter the for-loop, while the others do not. Therefore, some (but not all) threads of the warp hit the `__syncthreads()`. CUDA specification says that when that happens, the behaviour is undefined.

It can happen that warp gets out of sync and some threads already begin loading next chunk of data, halting on next instances of `__syncthreads()` while previous threads are still stuck in your previous loop.

I am not sure though if that is what you are going to face in this particular case.

Comment: As with the unrolled code, im checking my code with the Nvidia reduction.pdf and i think the code is the same =/. I believe what you say is true though

Comment: Looking at the code i dont see why some threads dont enter the for-loop. I see that only some threads(tid<stride) enter the if condition, but i dont know why some threads dont enter the for-loop

Comment: I got what you said, if the stride is for ex 16, tid from 0 to 16 enter the for, while the others do not(that was what you meant i suppose). I think that branching holly happens with the if condition, but i dont know if there is a problem with that. What i know is that its supposed to be less efficient

Answer (score 0):

I see you're doing Reduction Sum in kernel. Here's a good [presentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1_1/Website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) by NVIDIA for optimizing reduction on GPUs. You'll notice that the same code that was giving a throughput of **2 GB/s is optimized to 63 GB/s** in this guide.